# How can I block kernel upgrade beyond a specific version?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

On a number of machines (Ubuntu 22.04) I have kernel 5.15.0-X installed. Upgrading I get kernel 5.15.0-Y but, unfortunately, compatibility with a system software is broken. I know that the latest useful version is Z where X < Z < Y. I would like to upgrade the kernel and make sure that the upgrade doesn't go beyond version Z, until I fix the compatibility issue. How could I do? Consider that there are several tens of servers and I should automate (Ansible) the operations.